# HTML string is not Working in MAC Catalyst

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst

HTML attributed string is not working in Mac Catalyst but it is working fine on iPhone and iPad. HTML String code are the below.

```
var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
```

And the error in Mac Catalyst is

connection to service on pid 17352 named com.apple.textkit.nsattributedstringagent: Exception caught during decoding of reply to message 'renderHTML:options:withReply:', dropping incoming message and calling failure block.

Ignored Exception: Exception while decoding argument 1 (#2 of invocation):

```
<NSInvocation: 0x600001802d80>
return value: {v} void
target: {@?} 0x0 (block)
argument 1: {@} 0x7fff85206780
argument 2: {@} 0x0
argument 3: {@} 0x0

Exception: value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSColor'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSNull,
    UIColor,
    NSArray
)}'.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think its a bug of Mac Catalyst.
NSAtrributed String generating NSColor which is not supported in Catalyst